# how to set width and height of Viewport in ext.Net

Tags: asp.net, viewport, ext.net

I am working with Ext.Net1.0. and **I am working with ext:Desktop and  ext:Viewport**
I want to fit my page on the screen, whatever resolution is there and not allowing scaling.
How to fit my page in Ext.Net??

[image]

My Desktop and view look like above Image.In one Window I have take view port and give north and center layout to that.

In center I have take one Panel in that take 2 more panel with half width. like left panel and right panel in display.

but in all panel **i have give explicitly width and height to all my panel**(like outer panel is of 1000 width so inner 2 panel is of 500 width) thats way it willnot set accordingly my screen layout. so how can i??

Comment: By default Viewport and Desktop scale to page size http://examples1.ext.net/Examples/ViewPort/Basic/Built_in_Markup/ , http://examples1.ext.net/Examples/Desktop/Introduction/Overview/Desktop.aspx . Can you describe more details about your problem or provide any example code?

Comment: This is basically the purpose of Viewport...to resize to the, errr..viewport! Are you not seeing this behaviour?

Comment: @dougajmcdonald view my question again I have write my question briefly

Comment: You would want to set 'fitlayout' on your viewport to make it fit the window and then within that use a 'ext:columnlayout' compontn to split the internal part in two

Comment: @dougajmcdonald Thanks alot..Done through 'ext:columnlayout'

Comment: @dougajmcdonald I have another Query about Ext.Desktop can you please help me [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749990/how-to-hide-start-button-in-ext-net-desktop[/link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to set 'fitlayout' on your viewport to make it fit the window and then within that use a 'ext:columnlayout' component to split the internal part in two